# How to get Jar dependencies list

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to list down all the dependencies of jar file which is created through maven project build. How can I acheive this in java ? I know it through maven command `mvn:dependency` but i want to do it programmatically..
Any Help?

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree`? what do you mean by programmatically ? For what purpose?

Comment: i mean in java .. if jar file path is given can i get to know its dependents jars(3rd party jars) ?

Comment: The jar file will not really help...cause you need to have a pom file (in general if you build the jar using Maven the pom file is usually contained in the jar but not necessarily). So far you have answered to use Java..but what is the purpose of this? What kind of problem are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is difficult. What you can do:

1. Grab the pom.xml of the jar, put it into an empty directory and call "mvn dependency:list" through ProcessBuilder. Parse the result and you have a list of the dependencies. This may fail, though, if the pom.xml cannot be interpreted as the pom of an independent project (e.g. if it is part of a multi-module build).
2. Try Aether to determine a list of dependencies instead of using ProcessBuilder. The potential problems are the same as above.

Comment: Instead of Aether you should use http://maven.apache.org/resolver/index.html which is the migrated Aether project...

Answer (score 0):

The following brute force method can successfully get all the absolute paths of dependency (3rd party) jars. Replace 'FileUtils.getFileListRecursively' and 'FileUtils.readLines' with your own methods.

```
FileUtils.getFileListRecursively("src")
```

reads the absolute file paths from the 'src' folder of your current java project, and

```
FileUtils.readLines(filePath)
```

reads the file as a text file and returns all lines as an ArrayList of Strings.

```
    HashSet<String> jarLocationsSet = new HashSet<>();

    final String importString = "import ";
    final String javaString = "java";
    ArrayList<String> fileList = FileUtils.getFileListRecursively("src");
    for (String filePath : fileList) {
        if (filePath.endsWith(javaString) == false){
            continue;
        }
        List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(filePath);

        for (String line : lines) {

            int isecl = line.indexOf(';');
            if (line.contains(importString) == false || isecl < 0){
                continue;
            }
            if (line.contains("static")){
                continue;
            }
            int start = line.indexOf(importString);
            line = line.substring(start + importString.length(), isecl);
            if (line.startsWith(javaString)){
                continue;
            }
            Class<?> clazz = null;
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName(line, false, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (clazz == null){
                continue;
            }


            URL location = clazz.getResource('/'+clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
            String locationString = location.toString();
            int jarIndex= locationString.indexOf(".jar");
            if (jarIndex < 0){
                continue;
            }
            locationString = locationString.substring(0, jarIndex + 4);
            jarLocationsSet.add(locationString);
        }

    }


    for (String jarLocation : jarLocationsSet) {
        System.out.println("jarLocation = " + jarLocation);
    }
```

Comment: Edit: This method can get all jar files that are used (any one class in the jar file is used) at least once in this java project.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to read the pom file and find out what's inside because one dependency can be imported with different version numbers several times by other dependencies, and it can get very deep, maven has its own way to decide which version to use. The general idea is to read the final jar file and find the folder where all the jars are inside.

```
RuntimeMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
String classPath = bean.getClassPath();//    /opt/spring-boot/app.jar
ZipFile jarFile = new ZipFile(classPath);
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
                if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                 system.out.println( zipEntry.getName());  
                }
            }
```